# do some action after expected condition is met

Tags: c#, selenium, nunit

I am using Nunit to run selenium test. I am using Nunit AssertionHelper class.

So i have below condition written in my c# file

```
Expect(() => page.ToastTitle, Is.EqualTo("Ok").After(1.Seconds()), "Totally wrong");
```

This works as expected but what i want to is to add some action after i get success message as Ok in same Expect condition.

Is it possible? Any idea how i can implement this?

Comment: What kind of action do you need to perform after asserting the page title? Also, is the point of this test to assert the page title is correct, or are you using this as a signal that you can continue to the next part of the test?

Comment: @GregBurghardt exactly as you said as to use a signal so i continue with next part of test

Comment: Ok. Can you give more information about the "next step" that you want to take?

Comment: The default should be to continue the test UNLESS the assert fails. Do asserts not stop the test on failure?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using the page title as a signal that you can continue on with your test, you'll want to use a WebDriverWait object:

```cs
var timeToWait = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeToWait);

wait.Until(d => page.ToastTitle == "Ok");

// Do the next thing in your test
```

If the toast title is not `"Ok"` after one second, Selenium throws a `WebDriverTimeoutException`, which should fail the test.

An extension method is pretty easy to write and is really handy to have:

```cs
public static class WebDriverExtensions
{
    public static void WaitUntil<TResult>(this IWebDriver driver, Func<IWebDriver, TResult> condition, int secondsToWait = 30)
    {
        var wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait));

        wait.Until(condition);
    }
}
```

This makes waiting for something a little more intuitive to use:

```cs
driver.WaitUntil(d => page.ToastTitle = "Ok");

// Perform the next step in your test.
```